# Flattened 3D array interior values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a flattened 3D array representing the vertex indices of a procedural mesh that I'm trying to optimize.  I create the array like so:

```
int* vertIndices = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT * DEPTH];
```

and to add to the array

```
vertIndices[x + WIDTH * (y + HEIGHT * z)] = vertIndex;
```

The issue is that I only need to keep track of the vertices on the *surface* of the mesh.  Interior vertices do not get created.

Therefore, I'm creating a lot of wasted integers that never get used.

Here is a loop through the vertIndices array of a mesh with WIDTH: 7, HEIGHT: 7 and DEPTH: 7

[image]

All those -1163005939 values are vertices that would be located within the interior of the mesh but do not get created.

My question is how can I improve the formula

```
x + WIDTH * (y + HEIGHT * z)
```

to ignore interior values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you won't get around of introducing some kind of condition to the formula. Something like this:

```
int getIndex(int x, int y, int z) {
    //First get the amount of points in all layers before this z layer.
    int beforeZ = (z) ? WIDTH*HEIGHT + (z - 1)*2*(WIDTH + HEIGHT - 2) : 0;

    //Then get the amount of points within this layer before this line.
    int beforeY = (y) ? WIDTH + 2*(y - 1) : 0;
    if(z == 0 || z == DEPTH - 1) beforeY = y*WIDTH;

    //And finally the amount of points within this line before this point.
    int beforeX = (x) ? 1 : 0;
    if(z == 0 || z == DEPTH - 1 || y == 0 || y == HEIGHT - 1) beforeX = x;

    //Return the amount of points before this one.
    return beforeZ + beforeY + beforeX;
}
```

I admit that this is a bit ugly, but I think it's quite close to the best you can get. At least if you don't want to create some kind of lookup table that matches coordinates to indices and vice versa. Such lookup tables would, of course, be the really big gun that can handle any case, with the drawback of quite significant memory usage and likely slower operation.